# react google map not appearing

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

react-google-maps is not showing on screen. I have a Home component that is rendering a container MapNavigation component that is rendering view Map Component. Basically is Home -> MapNavigation -> Map

I am trying to get a simple map showing up, but is not working.

I am following this tutorial -> https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/basics/simple-map

When I check the elements in the browser it shows that the div exists but it isn't populated with any map.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk59M.png)

What am I missing?

Home.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Posts, MapNavigation} from '../containers';


class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        Home Layout
        <div className='row'>

          <div className='col-md-3'>
            <MapNavigation/>
          </div>

          <div className='col-md-6'>
            <Posts/>
          </div>
          <div className='col-md-3'>
            Account
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Home
```

MapNavigation.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map } from '../view';

class MapNavigation extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        MapNavigation
        <div>
            <Map />
        </div>


      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MapNavigation;
```

Map.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker} from 'react-google-maps';

class Map extends Component {

  render() {

    const GettingStartedGoogleMap = withGoogleMap( props => (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={3}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: -25.363882, lng: 131.044922 }}
        >


      </GoogleMap>

    ))


    return (
        <GettingStartedGoogleMap
          containerElement={
            <div style={{height: `100%`, width: `100%`}} />
          }

          mapElement={
            <div style={{height: `100%`, width: `100%`}} />
          }

          />
    )


  }
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: Are there any errors in console?

Comment: There are no errors in the console.

Comment: Can you unfold the other div too? Its the one that should contain google maps elements.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by unfolding the other div?

I am giving all the div element that is wrapping google-map elements a height and width of 100% and is still showing nothing.

Comment: Compare your DOM with the one from https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/basics/simple-map and you see that the div containing the map elements is above the one that you highlighted in your screenshot.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you, I will try to fix it.

Comment: It didn't work I have no idea why that div is underneath it. How can I fix it? My code looks like tom chen, but the div is underneath.

Comment: Without more information, I'm afraid there is not much more I can help. My intuition is that the map is actually loaded but for some reason the map div renders either outside your viewport or as 0x0 pixel div.

Comment: Hey, this is a repo I uploaded.
https://github.com/spaceforestchu/google_map_react

I would be appreciated if you can take a look. Thanks in advance.

Comment: nevermind I fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's look like stylesheet of your html have problems with `style={{height:`100%`, width:`100%`}}`.

You can try replace your style of map to 1000px to test.

```
return (
    <GettingStartedGoogleMap
      containerElement={
        <div style={{height: `1000px`, width: `1000px`}} />
      }

      mapElement={
        <div style={{height: `1000px`, width: `1000px`}} />
      }

      />
)
```

If map display, try fix your html stylesheets